# remembering a selected row in ListView in a fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

I have a listview inside a fragment. This listview has the following `longClick` listener.

```
private AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener receivedListItemLongClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long arg3) {
        Object object = reeceivedListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
        showDialog(OPTIONS_DIALOG_FRAGMENT);
        return true;
    }

};
```

It launches a new list `AlertDialog` which has an option to delete to undo the row selected in the parent fragment. 
I am able to pass the selection back from the `AlertView` to the parent but I can not remember which row was selected. What would be the correct way to remember this data?

Comment: the row was the position that you long clicked

Comment: where do you write this part of code ? is it in your adapter ?

Answer (score 0):

make a variable to store that data for you n your adapter like below:
in your adapter:

```
int lastSelectedRowByLongClick = -1;
```

then in your long click:

```
private AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener receivedListItemLongClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long arg3) {
    lastSelectedRowByLongClick = position;
    Object object = reeceivedListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
    showDialog(OPTIONS_DIALOG_FRAGMENT);
    return true;
}

};
```

and the best practice is to put delete and whatever function also in your adapter like so :

```
public void deleteLastLongedPressed()
{
 if(lastSelectedRowByLongClick != -1)
 {
  //TODO: write the logic to delete the row
  ///
  //then set the variable to -1 again so nothing happens if no one was selected
   lastSelectedRowByLongClick= -1;
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but this might not work if the fragment is destroyed or a new instance of the fragment is created. Plus I feel maintaining an instance variable to keep track of the last row selected isnt an elegant solution. If I wanted to do it this way. I wouldnt be asking for "What would be the correct way to remember this data?" I want to know If Android prodes a specific way to do it in the right way.

Comment: android doesnt provide any way to tell you the history of some view clicks or anything. its something you should take care of if you need it. if you dont want the variable to wipe if the fragment is destroyed make it static. believe me its the best you can do

Comment: I agree that it will work. But I am trying to figure out the right way to do it. how about passing it as extra variable with intent. Something like `intent.putExtra( EXTRAS_KEY, extras );` something like this?

Comment: Passig data to where ? To fragment ?

Comment: from Fragment to AlertDialog.